# Delphi: uses IdGlobalProtocols cause memory leak

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, indy

if i add `IdGlobalProtocols` unit by indy into my project, fastmm log a memory leak caused by `TIdCriticalSection`. If i remove `IdGlobalProtocols` from my uses list the leak desappear.

this happen even if i only start and close an empty form, eg.

**Project3.dpr**

```
program Project3;

uses
  sharemem,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

**Unit2.pas**

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  IdGlobalProtocols;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

**Project3_FastMM_Log.txt**

```
--------------------------------2017/4/21 17:44:57--------------------------------
Leak di un blocco. La dimensione è: 36

Questo blocco è stato allocato dal thread 0x14F8, e lo stack trace (indirizzo restituito) in quel momento era:
406E62 [System.pas][System][@GetMem$qqri][4614]
407CA3 [System.pas][System][TObject.NewInstance$qqrv][16452]
4084CA [System.pas][System][@ClassCreate$qqrpvzc][17790]
505D06 [System.SyncObjs.pas][System.SyncObjs][Syncobjs.TCriticalSection.$bctr$qqrv][1032]
4149A2 [Winapi.Windows.pas][Winapi.Windows][Windows.GetProcAddress$qqsuipb][35524]
5E8897 
40964C [System.pas][System][InitUnits$qqrv][22339]
4096B8 [System.pas][System][@StartExe$qqrp23System.PackageInfoTablep17System.TLibModule][22411]
410517 [SysInit.pas][SysInit][@InitExe$qqrpv][1419]
5E898C 
74D6337A [BaseThreadInitThunk]
773A9882 [Unknown function at RtlInitializeExceptionChain]
773A9855 [Unknown function at RtlInitializeExceptionChain]

Il blocco è attualmente usato da una istanza della classe: TIdCriticalSection

Il numero di allocazione è: 378

Dump della memoria di 256 byte partendo dall'indirizzo del puntatore 7EF9EB60:
2C A4 5C 00 F8 13 2A 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
AA A4 57 B5 80 80 80 80 00 00 00 00 91 FD F9 7E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
7D 01 00 00 62 6E 40 00 6F 9B 40 00 FC 9F 40 00 02 89 5E 00 4C 96 40 00 B8 96 40 00 17 05 41 00
8C 89 5E 00 7A 33 D6 74 82 98 3A 77 55 98 3A 77 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F8 14 00 00 F8 14 00 00
7E 6E 40 00 29 9C 40 00 99 AF 40 00 23 C0 40 00 B9 EC 5D 00 E1 EC 5D 00 E0 95 40 00 CF 89 5E 00
7A 33 D6 74 82 98 3A 77 55 98 3A 77 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 B0 04 02 00 89 46 31 4A
,  ¤  \  .  ø  .  *  .  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
ª  ¤  W  µ  €  €  €  €  .  .  .  .  ‘  ý  ù  ~  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
}  .  .  .  b  n  @  .  o  ›  @  .  ü  Ÿ  @  .  .  ‰  ^  .  L  –  @  .  ¸  –  @  .  .  .  A  .
Œ  ‰  ^  .  z  3  Ö  t  ‚  ˜  :  w  U  ˜  :  w  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  ø  .  .  .  ø  .  .  .
~  n  @  .  )  œ  @  .  ™  ¯  @  .  #  À  @  .  ¹  ì  ]  .  á  ì  ]  .  à  •  @  .  Ï  ‰  ^  .
z  3  Ö  t  ‚  ˜  :  w  U  ˜  :  w  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  °  .  .  .  ‰  F  1  J
```

What i doing wrong?

I'm on Delphi Berlin Update 2

Comment: You're explicitly using `ShareMem` but are then asking `FastMM` to tell you about memory leaks... surely this shouldn't be expected to work.

Comment: There are actually **3 intentional leaked objects** in Indy, when `FREE_ON_FINAL` is not defined in `IdCompilerDefines.inc` (it is not defined by default) - 2 in the `IdThread` unit (a global `TIdThreadSafeInteger` object is leaked, and it internally contains a `TIdCriticalSection` object) and 1 in the `IdStack` unit (a global `TIdCriticalSection` object).  However, those leaks are registered with the Memory Manager (via `System.RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak()`), so they shouldn't be getting reported.  So it sounds like maybe when `ShareMem` is used, leak registration doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes, without `ShareMem` and with `initialization ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := true`, no leak are reported.